# Haskell webdriver: how to get Elements contents?

Tags: haskell, webdriver

## Problem:

I am trying to make a web scraper with Haskell and the webdriver package, I am triyng to get the
attributes and inner html of the elements of the html, I tried to use the function show, but it just
shows a UUID, because Element is a newtype of text and it is and UUID, so I have no Idea of how to
get the contents of a Element.

## Dependencies:

```yaml
dependencies:
- base >= 4.7 && < 5
- http-client
- http-client-tls
- bytestring
- webdriver
- text
```

## Code:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Main (main) where
import Test.WebDriver
import System.IO
import Control.Monad (mapM, mapM_)
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO)
import qualified Data.Text as Text
import Control.Concurrent (threadDelay)
newtype Attr = {
    attrName    :: String
   ,attrContent :: String
   } deriving (Show)
firefoxConfig :: WDConfig
firefoxConfig = hilf $ useBrowser firefox defaultConfig
  where
    hilf m = m { wdHTTPRetryCount = 100 } {-, wdCapabilities = defaultCaps {
      additionalCaps = [ ("moz:firefoxOptions", object
        [ ("args", Array (fromList [String "--headless"])) ]
            )]  }} -}
main :: IO ()
main = runSession firefoxConfig $
  openPage "https://www.youtube.com/c/SomeChannel/videos" >>
  liftIO (threadDelay $ 10 * 1000000) >>
  findElems (ByXPath "//*[@id=\"video-title\"]") >>= \user_data ->
  liftIO (mapM_ (putStrLn . show . getAttrs) user_data)
  >> closeSession
  where getAttrs :: Element -> [Attr]
        getAttrs elment = ??????????? -- I need get the Attributes of the element
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting the content, I think you want [`getText`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/webdriver-0.9.0.1/docs/Test-WebDriver-Commands.html#v:getText), and for getting a single attribute there is [`attr`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/webdriver-0.9.0.1/docs/Test-WebDriver-Commands.html#v:attr), both from `Test.WebDriver.Commands`. The latter has type `(HasCallStack, WebDriver wd) => Element -> Text -> wd (Maybe Text)`. It takes an element ID and an attribute name and fetches `Just` the attribute value, or `Nothing` for the `null` case when the attribute isn’t present.

For *listing* all the attributes, it looks like Selenium doesn’t define an API, so I think you’ll need to use `executeJS`, something like this (untested):

```
getAttributes element = executeJS [element]
  "var result = {};\n\
  \var attrs = arguments[0].attributes;\n\
  \for (var i = 0; i < attrs.length; ++i)\n\
  \  result[attrs[i].name] = attrs[i].value;\n\
  \return result;"
```

You also won’t be able to use the pure type `Element -> [Attr]`, you’ll need to remain in the WebDriver `WD` context.

If a command is missing, you can also always use the lower-level functions like [`doElemCommand`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/webdriver-0.9.0.1/docs/Test-WebDriver-Commands-Internal.html#v:doElemCommand) from `Test.WebDriver.Commands.Internal` to invoke it directly, using the Selenium command URLs:

```
getAttribute :: (HasCallStack, WebDriver wd) => Text -> Element -> wd Text
getAttribute attribute element
  = doElemCommand methodGet element
    ("/attribute/" <> urlEncode attribute)
    Null
```

However, it’s better to avoid this if possible.